# Quickbooks sales order update - QBXML

Tags: c#, quickbooks, qbxml

Is there a way to update a sales order which is already created before?

I use C# and qbxml, but I couldn't find any XML statement or link about that. Is it possible or not?

Comment: Have you tried updating already and if so, what have you tried?

Comment: No i havent tried updating. i dont even know if it is possible. Because when I take a look at the sample codes which locates [here](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0085_QuickBooks_Windows_SDK/010_qb/0050_Documentation/Sample_Code). there is no update xml

Comment: I finally found the answer. Well in order to update/modify a sales order. We need to use "SalesOrderModRq" option.

Comment: If you've found the answer to your question then please post it here and mark it as accepted. There are others in the community that could possibly benefit from this sort of information.

Comment: @MCeley i couldnt post it first i found it because there was reputation limit :)

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.  To accept an answer, you click the check mark under the voting arrows on your question. Thanks for sharing your solution.

Comment: I will but it says i could do it tomorrow. you'r welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer. Well, in order to update/modify a sales order, we need to use the "SalesOrderModRq" option.

Here is my example:

```
<?qbxml version="11.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <SalesOrderModRq>
            <SalesOrderMod>
                <TxnID>1407-1346251803</TxnID>
                <EditSequence>1354787709</EditSequence>

                <SalesOrderLineMod>
                    <TxnLineID>1409-1346251803</TxnLineID>
                    <ItemRef>
                        <FullName>Item</FullName>
                    </ItemRef>
                    <Desc>Item Description</Desc>
                    <Quantity>5</Quantity>
                    <Rate>10.00</Rate>
                    <Amount>50.00</Amount>
                    <IsManuallyClosed>false</IsManuallyClosed>
                </SalesOrderLineMod>
            </SalesOrderMod>
        </SalesOrderModRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```